# Powershell Script which reads text files in smaller batches.

Tags: powershell, email, smtp, exchange-server

I have come across an issue when sending SMTP email, to a number of email address approx. 200. I am looking for a script in which it reads a .txt file containing the 200 email addresses and in smaller batches, sends an generic SMTP message using the script below.

The script which sends the generic email is below:

```
$to = "TO EMAIL"
$smtp = "SMTP Server"
$from = "FROM EMAIL"
$subject = "Subject" 
$body = "EMAIL BODY"
send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -Bcc (Get-Content "\\FILE Location") -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -Priority high
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Keep noted that there is a MessageRateLimit limit in Exchange, which you will also hit when using another approach. To change that check [Set-ThrottlingPolicy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298094(v=exchg.160).aspx) and MessageRateLimit (more infos [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232205(v=exchg.160).aspx)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution (there might be other/better ways):

```
$to = "TO EMAIL"
$smtp = "SMTP Server"
$from = "FROM EMAIL"
$subject = "Subject" 
$body = "EMAIL BODY"

$Recipient = Get-Content "emails.txt"
$NumberOfBatches = [int]($Recipient.count / 50)

For ($i = 0; $i -lt $NumberOfBatches; $i++) { 
    $Emails = $Recipient | Select -First 50 -Skip ($i * 50)
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -Bcc $Emails -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -Priority high
}
```

This loads the list of emails address in to a variable named `$Recipient`.

It then gets a count for how many batches there would need to be to send it 50 emails at a time, casting this as [int] to get a round number.

It then uses a `For` loop to do the number of batches defined, and uses the `Select-Object` cmdlet to filter the list of emails by the defined batches, by using `-First` and `-Skip`.

Comment: just as an idea to improve that. To avoid a "per x min message limit" as mentioned in my comment you might add a wait statement here until the next batch of emails is send out.